# CSS + jQuery: scale, center and rotate image along its container's rectangle

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, center

I'd like to do some tricky transformations with CSS (and jQuery, if necessary).

What I'd like to achieve:

- I have a **container** with width/height either set by fixed pixel values or a percentage (example: blue rectangle, 600px x 1000px)
- In this container, an [image with known original dimensions](http://www.nerdy-birdy.com/sketches/logotfs/line1.jpg) (in my case, 1000px x 200px) should be

  - **rotated around its own center** (the + in the middle of the image) along the container's diagonal axis, and
  - **placed in the container's center** (vertical, horizontal), and
  - **scaled** to not exceed the container.

The result would look like this:
[image]

Can a CSS/jQuery expert help me out on how to achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: So... do you want the end result to look exactly like your image? A large blue square that remains stationary, and a smaller green rectangle inside it at an angle? Do you want it constantly rotating as an animation or just static, as is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should the result be static, or animated/responsive, depending on screen/box size?

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
transform: rotate(66deg) translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
```

To Rotate:
`transform: rotate(66deg);`

Centerpoint: 
`transform-origin: 0% 0%;`

Center absolute container:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
```

Static example: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGwozM

:)

Comment: This did the trick, thanks very much. If somebody wants to see a dynamic approach that updates on the window's resize, take a look here: https://www.nerdy-birdy.com/sketches/logotfs/

Answer (score 0):

I've made a script that actually calculates how the elements will fit for every possible size. When you have an element `.fitChildren`, it will fit all child elements with a `rotation` attribute.

### Check out [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/zw6dbwL9/)

It accepts long texts and it also supports paddings.

This is the JavaScript

```
function fit () {
  $('.fitChildren').each(function(){
    var p = $(this)
    var pw = p.width()
    var ph = p.height()
    p.children('[rotation]').each(function(){
      var c = $(this)
      var cw = c.data('width')
      var ch = c.data('height')
      var ta = c.data('tan')
      var co = c.data('cos')
      var wi = pw / ((cw + (ch * ta)) * co * 2)
      var he = ph / ((ch + (cw * ta)) * co * 2)
      c.css({'transform':'translate(-50%,-50%)rotate('+c.data('angle')+'deg)scale('+(wi<he?wi:he)+')'})
    })
  })
}
$(function(){
  $('.fitChildren > [rotation]').each(function(){
    var t = $(this)
    var a = t.attr('rotation') % 360
    var rad = Math.abs(a) % 180
    if(rad > 90)rad = 180 - rad
    rad *= (Math.PI / 180)
    t.data({angle:a,tan:Math.tan(rad),cos:Math.cos(rad),width:t.outerWidth()/2,height:t.outerHeight()/2})
  })
  fit()
})
$(window).on('resize',function(){fit()})
```

The script starts out with creating internal data for all elements with the `rotation` attribute. The object stores five properties:

- angle `[rotation]`
- the angles tangent
- the angles cosine
- the elements width
- the elements height

Then when the the document is ready and when a resize occurs, `fit()` is called, which will loop through all elements and fit them inside their parents.

Hope this helps